# Is there a standard library function, opposite from addressof?

Tags: c++

I have an algorithm where am converting to from pointers to a class

```
std::vector<MyClass>  input;
std::vector<MyClass*> ptrs;
std::vector<MyClass>  output;
```

So to obtain the `ptrs` I do

```
transform(input.begin(), input.end(), back_inserter(ptrs), addressof<MyClass>);
```

Is there an **opposite operation** in the standard library, like `deref_of` so that I could get the result as :

```
transform(ptrs.begin(), ptrs.end(), back_inserter(output), deref_of<MyClass*>);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html).

```
std::copy(boost::make_indirect_iterator(ptrs.begin()),
          boost::make_indirect_iterator(ptrs.end()),
          std::back_inserter(output));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e179e610c148fbe)

Answer (score 6):

No such thing exist in the standard library.

However, you can write it yourself:

```
template<typename T>
T& deref(T * ptr) { return *ptr; }                //non-const version

template<typename T>
T const & cderef(T const * ptr) { return *ptr; }  //const version
```

You've to use it as `deref<MyClass>`, not `deref<MyClass*>`.

---

In C++14, you can use generic lambda to simply it:

```
auto deref = [](auto * ptr) { return *ptr; };
```

Now you could use just `deref` instead of `deref<MyClass>` (as in the previous case). The type will be inferred by the compiler, anyway. Of course, you could implement this in C++11 (or even in C++03)  as:

```
static const struct deref_t  //static const applies to the object
{
    template<typename T>
    T& operator()(T const * ptr) const { return *ptr; }

}deref;  //declare an object as well.
```

Use it as `deref`. It is just like generic lambda.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you need `cderef`? If I pass a `int const*` to `deref<>`, I get `int const& deref<int const>(int const*)`.

Comment: @MSalters: Not really. But `cderef<int>` looks shorter than `deref<int const>` . Just being friendly.